GLS combined with Random Effect
My data consists of repeated measurements (duration) per individual (ID). The fixed effect is habitat, the goal is to see if duration depends on habitat. However, the variance seems to differ quite a lot by individual, i.e. some individuals have always about the same duration, and for other individuals it varies a lot.
Is it reasonable to use a random effect for ID (to account for different intercept per individual) plus generalized least squares (to account for different variability per individual)?
In R, I'm using the package nmle and the model would be of the form:
model <- lme(  
  fixed = Duration ~ Habitat,  
  random = ~ 1 | ID,  
  weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | ID),  
  data = dataset  
)

With this approach, it will additionally cost as many degrees of freedom as there are individuals. Is there a different approach that only uses 1 parameter to account for this variability in the variance, like a variance parameter for the variance, same as the random effect does for the intercept? Or am I overthinking/underthinking something here.
The residuals would look really nice with the model above. But I'm not sure about the estimates, uncertainty and justification. For a report, can I compare this model to a null model in ANOVA, both fitted with ML method, and report the likelihood ratio and $p$-value? Can I still use pseudo $R^2$ from MuMiN::r.squaredGLMM and the standard error from the summary table?

Questions: Is your data perhaps zero-inflated? Maybe a Gamma-GLMM would be more appropriate for durations?


Is it reasonable to use a random effect for ID (to account for different intercept per individual) plus generalized least squares (to account for different variability per individual)?

I think there may be a little bit of confusion here. Often we would fit a model with gls to take care of the dependencies within groups/individuals, OR we would fit a model with random effects to do the same thing. Mixed effects models are well suited to address the situation here. I have not come across a situation where random effects AND gls are applied together. A model with appropriate random effects can take care of both of your requirements: to have random intercepts for individuals, AND to account for different variability per individual (by using random slopes and/or appropriate residual covariance structures).
In R, one of the most popular packages for fitting gls models and mixed effects models is nlme (with the gls and lme functions respectively). The authors of this package, Pinheiro and Bates, also published an accompanying book "Mixed-Effects Models in S and S-PLUS" and on page 250 they say:

The gls function is used to fit the extended linear model (5.5), using
either maximum likelihood, or restricted maximum likelihood. It can be
viewed as an lme function without the argument random

So, with the nlme package, you can fit a mixed effects model, OR a generalised least squares model to account for the non-independent observations within groups.
If you really, really, really want to analyse your data with random effects AND generalised least squares, then you could try something like this:
library(lme4)
library(Matrix)

# Example dataset
set.seed(15)
df <- data.frame(
  y = rnorm(100),
  x = rnorm(100),
  group = factor(rep(1:10, each = 10))
)

# Fit initial model to estimate variance components
initial_model <- lmer(y ~ x + (1 | group), data = df)

# Extract variance components
vc <- as.data.frame(VarCorr(initial_model))
sigma_u <- vc[1, "vcov"] # Random intercept variance
sigma_e <- attr(VarCorr(initial_model), "sc")^2 # Residual variance

# Design matrices
X <- model.matrix(~ x, data = df)
Z <- model.matrix(~ 1, data = df) # Random intercepts design matrix

# Number of groups and observations
n_groups <- length(unique(df$group))
n_obs <- nrow(df)

# Create block diagonal matrix for random effects
G <- sigma_u * Diagonal(n_groups)

# Create the Z matrix for the random effects
Z_block <- kronecker(Diagonal(n_groups), matrix(1, 10, 1))

# Construct V
V <- Z_block %*% G %*% t(Z_block) + sigma_e * Diagonal(n_obs)

# Invert V
V_inv <- solve(V)

# Compute GLS estimator
beta_gls <- solve(t(X) %*% V_inv %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% V_inv %*% df$y

# Display the results
beta_gls

However, I am not sure at all that it makes sense to do that !
